# Javascript Create Object inside Objects dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an empty object and want to create an object inside object dynamically.

```
const obj = {}
obj["test1"]["test1.1"] = x //initialize to some variable
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'test1.1' of undefined
```

I want the output to be like

```
obj = {
   test1: {
       test1.1: x //some variable
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `obj['test1'] = { 'test1.1': x }`

Comment: Or why not literally `const obj = { test1: { "test1.1": x } }`? Then you make the declaration, assignment, and full object creation all at once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By *dynamically* if you mean the name of the attribute is not certain, you can use brackets to insert dynamic variable names:

```js
const arg1 = 'test1';
const arg2 = 'test1.1';
const x = 42;

// assign both variable names dynamically
const obj = { [arg1]: { [arg2]: x } };
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Well guessed that this is what OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two steps or one

```js
const x = "some var";
const obj = {};

obj["test1"] = {
  "test1.1": x
}; // assign the nested object 
console.log(obj);

// or 

const y = "some var";

const obj1 = {  // assign the complete object 
  test1: {
    "test1.1": x
  }
}; 
console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `obj["test1"] = {}`

```js
const obj = {}
obj["test1"] = {}
obj["test1"]["test1.1"] = 'x'

console.log(obj)
```

---

### For the other solution using lodash library, you can use [set()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#setWith) method.

```js
var obj = {}
_.set(obj, ["test1", "test1.1"], 'x');
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did that too but is there any way I can do that in one line

Comment: You can use lodash setWith() method - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#setWith

Comment: can you add the lodash part to your answer so that I can mark that as the answer? I think it would help people if they are looking for the one line solution

Comment: i thought OP wants the dynamic key for the future use, and the question just was an example.  didn't notice that he definitely wanted that obj with one simple nested obj @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

A more functional approach

```js
const arr = {};

// respecting immutability
const rewroteArray = {...arr, da: {"foo": 2}}

console.log(rewroteArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

As creating an Object with this syntax `const obj = {}` is equal `const obj = new Object()`. You can use the second method to define any level deep of properties definition.

```js
const obj = new Object({
  "test1": {
    "test-1":'x'
  }
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: No need for `new Object()` at all